# How to add a set path only for that batch file executing?

Tags: path, batch-file, command, command-prompt

Basically, I know I can go through my control panel and modify the path variable. But, I'm wondering if there is a way to through batch programming have a temporary path included? That way it is only used during that batch file execution. I don't want to have people go in and modify their path variables just to use my batch file.

Answer (score 382, accepted):

Just like any other environment variable, with [`SET`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html):

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\whatever\else
```

If you want to have a little safety check built in first, check to see if the new path exists first:

```
IF EXIST c:\whatever\else SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\whatever\else
```

If you want that to be local to that batch file, use [`setlocal`](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html):

```
setlocal
set PATH=...
set OTHERTHING=...

@REM Rest of your script
```

Read the docs carefully for `setlocal`/`endlocal` , and have a look at the other references on that site - [Functions](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-functions.html) is pretty interesting too and the syntax is tricky.

The [Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html) page should get you started with the basics.

Comment: If you add a `setlocal` to your batch file, the path is only visible in the file

Comment: hw do you add "setlocal"? Is that in place of "SET"?

Comment: @micheal: updated my answer with links. Please read some documentation/examples/tutorials about cmd scripting - `SET` is really something you should know and understand before you do any scripting.

Comment: Life saver. I needed to add an EV on a server that couldn't be restarted and this allows me to do what I need without having to schedule a restart!

Comment: Even without `SETLOCAL` it's, at most, only going to be for that individual command prompt session -- if you're doing this from more than one batch file, and using `EXIT /B %N%`, then `SETLOCAL` is basically just going to dump your changes when the script exits. :-/

Comment: Why do you use `@REM` and not just `REM`? What does the `@` do?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye: `@` suppresses echo for that line

Comment: Is there a way to make a change to the system path which is immediate (No need to Restart) yet holds just until the next restart? Thank You.

Answer (score 35):

There is an important detail:

```
set PATH="C:\linutils;C:\wingit\bin;%PATH%"
```

does not work, while

```
set PATH=C:\linutils;C:\wingit\bin;%PATH%
```

works. The difference is the quotes!

UPD also see the comment by venimus

Comment: in fact it should be `SET "PATH=...%PATH%"` else spaces existing in path will cause errors or misbehavior. Wrapping in quotes like this will not include them but will properly set the variable. Same works for any other env variable.

Comment: Thank you @venimus for your comment. Both `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\newpath;` and `set PATH="%PATH%;C:\newpath;"` didn't work, but `set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\newpath;"` did.

Answer (score 23):

That's right, but it doesn't change it permanently, but just for current command prompt.

If you wanna to change it permanently you have to use for example this:

```
setx ENV_VAR_NAME "DESIRED_PATH" /m
```

This will change it permanently and yes, you can overwrite it in another batch script.

Comment: Maybe `/m` needs to be after `setx`?

Comment: Works the same for me, but this Win Batch Scripting is little unfinished business from MS. In my company where we have all the same laptops with same system there is not a universal script for PATH setting and we are maintaining 2 or 3 of them, so whatever works for you :)

Comment: Thanks for the update. In Windows Server 2012, when I put `/m` at the end, the `DESIRED_PATH` was added with /m at the end for current user only.

Comment: A word of caution. Using setx on a path, trying to add more to it, and the string is > 1024 long, I discovered that the result (my environment PATH) was truncated permanently. (A good thing that I had could copy the %PATH% I had ECHOed out before the change, and put it back using the Environment variables windows tool.)

Comment: Attention! This command directly overwrite the System Environment Variable! I had deleted them and try to fix them. 


And also for anyone who did this mistake: do not restart your computer. Write `echo %path%` and you'll get the current loaded path. You need to distinguish the User and System environment variables from each other. Then you can manually apply them to the correct place.