# Why doesn't tor work as a command on a window computer?

Tags: browser, command-line, passwords, command, tor

I've installed TOR(the onion routing) to with some scripts I've made. I tried to set a password for the TOR browser with:

```
tor --hash-password "My_password"
```

but the command line keeps putting out

```
'tor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Where's the exe?  Have you tried adding the path to the command?

Comment: @pennyrave you should show us how to do this!  (I am not familiar with windows).

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6832544/835512) has a pretty good description.

Answer (score 0):

@Lord Elrond

To do as @pennyrave said press win+R
write `cmd`
a terminal will appear, and write there -

```
cd C:\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor
```

there write your command with .exe

for eg. - tor.exe --hash-password "My_password"