# C# compiler (csc.exe) on Azure Pipelines

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-pipelines, csc

I've created a tool that needs you to have csc.exe compiler installed and added to PATH.

I want to test that the program works correctly using Azure Pipelines, but I don't know how to install and add it to PATH variable.

How can I do that (and remove the error `'csc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`)?

Here is my pipeline run:

https://dev.azure.com/LumitoLuma/GitHub/_build/results?buildId=30&view=logs&j=12f1170f-54f2-53f3-20dd-22fc7dff55f9

And here it's code:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=JAVA_HOME]$(JAVA_HOME_11_X64)"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH]$(JAVA_HOME_11_X64)\bin;$(PATH)"
  displayName: Setting up Java

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    arguments: 'install Microsoft.Net.Compilers'

- script: install.bat
  displayName: Installing JCC
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You can't do that because you have no guarantee of where `csc.exe` lives, or if it even exists, on Azure. Instead, make a C# executable that uses the `Microsoft.CSharp` NuGet package (or whatever package you need to do what you want).

Comment: There can be multiple C# compilers on the same machine, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-rough-history-of-the-so-many-c-compilers-f3a85500707c so you might choose what you really need or install the ones you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do that (and remove the error 'csc' is not recognized as an
> internal or external command, operable program or batch file.)?

The windows-hosted agent has corresponding VS installed. Since you're using `windows-latest` element, Azure DevOps will use the windows2019 with VS2019 installed for your pipeline. You can check the different paths for `Csc.exe` below:

For `VS2017 Enterprise`:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe
```

For `VS2019 Enterprise`:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe
```

For `.net 4.0 framework`:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
```

**Workaround:**

Use multi-line script to [Set the path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6832544/10910450) of `csc.exe` first, then call the `install.bat`.

```
- script: |
    SET PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\"
    install.bat
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

You can use script above when you're using `windows-latest` agent. And you can modify the path whenever you want to use another agent. Also, distinguish the difference between one-line script and multi-line script:

```
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```